# Parser not working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing

if i have,

```
str = "[App Version]+4-[Number 1 Q1-P3]"
```

i want an array like  :

```
arr[0] = App Version  
arr[1] = Number 1 Q1-P3
```

My current parser:

```
 var arr =str.replace(/[+/*//[]/g,'').split("]").slice(0, -1);  
    arr = arr.map(function(item){
       return item.replace(/^-/, '')
    });
```

It gives result:

```
arr[0] = App Version  
arr[1] = 4-Number 1 Q1-P3
```

I only want the name between [ ] in an array.
Can anyone provide a regex or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const input = "[App Version]+4-[Number 1 Q1-P3]";
const matches = input.match(/[^\[]+(?=\])/g);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Awesome !! Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50154099/parser-for-string
Please reply