# Parser for string

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing

Suppose i have a string,

```
 str = "Date()+Abs(9)Day()+45"
```

I want an array that contains:

```
arr[0]=Date()
arr[1]=Abs(9)
arr[2]=Day()
```

My current parser:

```
var temp = str.match(/\w+(\w+)/)
```

Please help

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve]

Comment: See this - https://jsfiddle.net/wLf8vd7m/3/ but this is not dynamic.

Comment: @NNR, it's kinda patch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a pretty easy expression.

```
/          -- START expression
  \w+      -- One or more alpha-numeric (plus '_')
  \(       -- Literal opening parenthesis
  [\w/-]*  -- Zero or more alpha-numeric (plus '_', '/', and '-')
  \)       -- Literal closing parenthesis
/g         -- END expression; Global match
```

```js
var str = "Date(20/04/98)+Abs(-9)Day(20/04/98)+45"
var arr = str.match(/\w+\([\w/-]*\)/g);

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2));

// arr[0] = Date(20/04/98)
// arr[1] = Abs(-9)
// arr[2] = Day(20/04/98)
```

### Learn more

- **Information**

  - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)
  - [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
  - [Regular-Expressions.info](https://regular-expressions.info)
  - [RegexBuddy](https://regexbuddy.com/regex.html)
- **Tools**

  - [RegExr](https://regexr.com) (Recommended)
  - [Dan's Tools - Regex Pal](https://regexpal.com) (same as [Regex Tester](https://regextester.com))
  - [regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but in this case,  
str = "Date(20/04/2018)+Abs(-6)" , it returns only ["Date(20/04/2018)"]

Comment: How to match negative numbers also?

Comment: Support dashes inside the parenthesis. I will update.

Comment: I want to match everyting between ( ) in the string; like str = "Date('20/04/18')+Abs(-6)" will return only Abs(-6)

Comment: Also if str = "Date(20/04/18)-Abs(-6)", it will give only Abs(-6)

Comment: It can also be empty str = "Date()+Now()"

Comment: @SagarChaudhary OK, you can customize it, I will update once more to match on ZERO or more... Please review the links I provided.

Comment: How can i match all characters a-z,0-9,special characters between (  )

Comment: If you want special characters, you need to modify the `[\w/-]*` bit. Try changing it to: `[\w/-\!@#\$%\^]*` for example.

Comment: but it also removes the actual operator like in str= "Date()-Now()"
it gives only Date()

Comment: So you want to keep the operators? That is an entirely different question. In your original question, you did not care about the operators.  I proved a solution to get what was required initially If you want to ask a different question, feel free to create a new post.